# text is beneath other text instead of next to it, though I haven't used any weird code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a quiz and the plan is when you click submit there is going to be some text next to the answers with some more information. But now, when I click on submit the information is displayed beneath the answers instead of next to it.
You can see the problem in question 2 answer 1 after submitting.

demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/OvcwBzfFte4A0F0NbNSi?p=preview

What can be the problem ?

```
    <style>
  .quizbox {
    width: 58%;
    max-width: 950px;
    border: 1px gray solid;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 7%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  .quizstyle {
    padding-right: 50%;
  }

  .row {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
</style>

<div class="quizbox">

  <!-- open main div -->
  <h1>Quiz</h1>
  <form id="form1" action=" ">
    <div class="quizstyle">
      <h3>Moths are a member of what order?</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Octagon</div>
      <div> </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Leprosy</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="33" />Lepidoptera</div>
      &nbsp;
      <h3>Question 2</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 1</div> <span id="demo"></span>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
      &nbsp;
      <h3>Question 3</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 2</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" />

  </form>Your grade is: <span id="grade">__</span>
  <p id="grade2"></p>

</div>
<!-- close main div -->


<span>fdf</span> <span>fdf</span><span>fdf</span>
fd
<script>
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      variable = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "variable"]:checked').value);
      sub = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "sub"]:checked').value);
      con = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "con"]:checked').value);

      result = variable + sub + con;

      document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;
      var result2 = "";
      if (result == 0) {
        result2 = "I don't think you studied."
      };
      if (result == 33) {
        result2 = "You need to spend more time. Try again."
      };
      if (result == 66) {
        result2 = "I think you could do better. Try again."
      };
      if (result == 99) {
        result2 = "Excellent!"
      };
      document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = result2;

      return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
    } //this ends the submit function
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
  }
</script>

hgf
<div> </div>
```

Comment: The span with the answer is inserted outside the row. That's why it starts on a new line.

Comment: Yea I saw that as well, I made it inside the div now, but it looks really messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these couple of changes, the text "Hello World" was getting displayed next to the answer.

Adding a css for the "demo" `span` tag to stay inline.

```
span#demo {
    display: inline;
}
/* A small bonus */
.quizstyle {
    padding-right: 20%;
}
```

Moving it inside your "row" `div` tag.

```
<div class="row">
    <input name="sub" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 1
    <span id="demo"></span>
</div>
```

Ofcourse, you'll have to work out the other detailing (like adding sufficient margin between your row div and demo span, providing enough width for the span to be shown on same line, reducing it's size, giving it some color, etc.), but this kind of achieves what your original requirement was.

Answer (score 0):

Just add float: right; for span#demo element